# WPF Unwanted margin around path

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg

I am trying to create my own symbol of square root which will be resizing automatically according to its content. Similar to the one at https://www.symbolab.com. I use XAML in WPF.

At the moment, the square root symbol looks like this:

[image: Root symbol]

The problem is the space between the first column and the second column of the grid, which both contain the path element using those I draw the root icon.
There is the small space that is making the line discrete (noncontinuous).

I am unable to make it disappear. It seems like the Path element creates it.

Is there anything I can do about it? I will also accept any other ideas how to create the required element (the square root symbol).

Here's the code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GUICalculator.View.CustomTextBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUICalculator.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="35" d:DesignWidth="40"
         Background="White">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="TrackSurface" Margin="5,5,0,5">
        <Path Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" 
                  Data="M0,10 L 5,14 L 14,0 L 15, 0">
        </Path>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Path VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="0" Height="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" 
                  Data="M 0,50 L 100,50">
        </Path>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Text="4" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Edit:** I managed to work around the problem by setting negative margin to the path. I believe there still might be a better solution though.

**Edit** As @Clemens suggested in the comments, there are properties that can be set on path element: `StrokeStartLineCap="Square"` and `StrokeEndLineCap="Square"`. It works as expected.

Comment: I would have thought as your font size grows, your two lines won't match. I think i'd probably have one polyline instead. Recalculate the points driven by events of the textbox. Textchanged and maybe contentrendered.

Comment: Set `StrokeStartLineCap="Square"` and `StrokeEndLineCap="Square"`.

Comment: @Clemens beautiful, exactly the feature I was looking for. Thank you very much.